# Laravel - Validate a date is before another date

Tags: php, laravel

I have default a validation rule in the RegisterController Laravel:

```php
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
]);
```

And I want to add a rule on a date given by the user to be before 2 weeks ahead.     Using this function you can better understand my need:

```php
$today = date('d-m-Y');
$dateofinfection = $data['last_donated'];
        
$validDateToDonate = strtotime($dateofinfection.'+ 2 week');
$validDateToDonate = date('d-m-Y',$validDateToDonate);


if($validDateToDonate > $today)
{
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors(['last_donated' => 'You have to wait at least 2 weeks after you recovered! ']);
}
```

Basically I want to get the input from the user **(last_donated)** , add 2 weeks to it and compare it with today date and returning an error if it is higher.

```
@if ($errors->has('last_donated'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('last_donated') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**way 1 :** you can make a rule for check date like following:
first make a rule

```
php artisan make:rule LastDonateRule
```

then go to the `LastDonateRule.php` file in the `app/Rules` path and check it in `passes` function:

```php
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return Carbon::now() > (new Carbon($value))->addWeeks(2) ? true : false;
}


public function message()
{
    return 'You have to wait at least 2 weeks after you recovered!';
}
```

after definition rule, call it in the validator:

```php
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    'last_donated' => ['required', 'date', new LastDonateRule()]
]);
```

**way 2 :** or use the Laravel validation like following:

```php
'last_donated' => 'required|before:+2 week',
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a line in your `Validator::make` like so:

```
'last_donated' => ['required', 'before:+2 week'],
```

This will force the `last_donated` to be before the 2 weeks ahead

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-before

Comment: Why'd I never used this before?

Comment: i discovered it recently, really neat rule

Comment: Imma refactor my app rn. I actually do have a rule in place that -- judging by Laravel's code -- has the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you added `today` as one of request parameters you could validate it relative to today inside validation string:

Add today's date server side: 
`$request->merge(['today' => Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->format("Y-m-d")]);`
Then:

```
Validator::make(
    $request->all(),
    ['last_donated' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|before:today +2 week']
)
```